# Azure Durable functions with Orchestrator : how to prevent re-running code IN-BETWEEN Azure functions?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have created an Azure function that has the `[OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context` parameter, making it an **orchestrator**.

This function calls many activities inside a loop, by using the `CallActivityAsync` method, as per Azure design.

At first I didn't pay attention to the whole "replay" nature of the orchestrator (i.e. I didn't realize that it would be re-run from the start every time an activity finished), but I'm there now.

It runs a lot of activities (maybe up to 10,000).

My problem is that there is some **control code** I'd like to run **in-between activites**.
This includes, but is not limited to :

- Calculating the performance by running the stopwatch on the first few items.
- Logging the overall progress (`activity 123 of 564654...`)

I simply don't know how to do that. The logging is re-logged from the beginning each time, rendering my computation of the overall progress useless.

Do you have a suggestion on the general spirit of how to achieve this? I've read the Azure documentation but I wish there were more practical examples.

Comment: Take a look at this article, especially on the replay-safe logger (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=csharp-inproc#app-logging). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=csharp-inproc#app-logging

Comment: If you have that many activities to run, I would recommend splitting the work into sub-orchestrators (100 chunks of 100 for example), the replays will load a lot less history rows and make it faster.

Comment: @silent thanks that helped. juunas I never thought of that; moving the logic upstream instead of downstream. Azure functions are so weird.